# How to derive the results of consecutive integration of a set of data? Converting acceleration to velocity

Tags: r

Suppose I collected acceleration data over time as follows:

```
    time<-seq(1,1000,10)
    acceleration<-runif(100,1.1,1.3)
```

How do I integrate acceleration at every time point accordingly to get velocity at every time point?

I am looking at trapz from the package pracma. I believe it returns the total AUC based on the first to the last time point.Should I be deriving this AUC separately or incrementally to get velocity at every time point?

Answer (score 0):

(I see no reason to use an extra package, so am admittedly not answering some of your questions about pkg:pracma.)

```
velocity = cumulative sum of acceleration * time intervals
```

So R code (over 10 intervals):

```
 time<-seq(1,100,10)
    acceleration<-runif(10,1.1,1.3) 
 time
# [1]  1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91
 acceleration
 #[1] 1.265110 1.120862 1.271631 1.133425 1.242377 1.181125 1.108523 1.259383 1.256101 1.159109
> veloc <- acceleration*diff(time)
Warning message:
In acceleration * diff(time) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
# so just remove the last accel-value, it tells us nothing

 veloc <- cumsum( head(acceleration,-1)*diff(time) )
#    result
 veloc
[1]  12.65110  23.85973  36.57604  47.91029  60.33406  72.14531  83.23054  95.82436 108.38538
```

These are velocities at `time = tail(time,-1)`, assuming velocity=0 at time=1.

I reasonably confident that this is the "correct" answer, but you might be interested in seeing what `pracma::trapz` says:

```
> pracma::trapz(time, acceleration)
[1] 107.8554
```

The difference may arise from this from the Details section of `?trapz`: "The points (x, 0) and (x, y) are taken as vertices of a polygon..."

I was assuming constant acceleration in the time intervals but perhaps one should have been assuming interpolated results? This seems to be what ``pracma::trapz was doing. See also:

```
> integrate( approxfun(time,acceleration), 1, 91)
107.8555 with absolute error < 0.01
```

And compare my notion of the course of acceleration:

```
plot( time,acceleration, xlim=c(1, 91), type="s")
```

With what approxfun would use:

```
plot( approxfun(time,acceleration), xlim=c(1, 91))
```